# Cakephp display select options as checkboxes but accept just a single choice

Tags: android, cakephp, select, checkbox

I know checkboxes should be boolean, but I'm trying to get this working in an Android Webview for a closed system which uses Android 4.4 (I can't change this version, nor can it be upgraded). Android 4.4 crashes if you present a drop down select box in a webview.

I know I can do this to present a "multiple choice checkbox" solution, but this allows multiple checkboxes to be selected ..

```
$this->Form->input('field_id', ['type' => 'select', 'multiple' => 'checkbox']);
```

Does anyone have any ideas? Or perhaps can suggest an alternative way of allowing a user to select from multiple options without using a Select box.

Cheers.

Comment: I assume you don't want to use radio buttons since you want to only take up one line of screen real-estate when not interacting with the screen?

Comment: @Roger .. I didnt try radio buttons, but that may well have worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using the great jQuery plugin "Chosen", which does not crash Android Kit Kat.

Comment: Did `radio` options didn't work? Did they have the same issue as `select`  or what?

Answer (score 1):

Use `radio` instead of `checkbox`. Maybe those don't have the same issues as select? And radio buttons are exactly this: checkboxes with only one option to be selected.